# Как сделать проверку типа данных

Tags: typescript

У меня есть собственный тип

```
type Example

    {
    id:string;
    Region:string;
    Fio:string;
    }
```

Как я могу проверить что переданных props в мой компонент это элемент данного типа
`if(typeof prop===Example)` не работает

Comment: Почитайте про `instanceof`

Comment: @EzioMercer, с `type` это не сработает

Comment: @Grundy Если почитать как это работает, то думаю можно догадаться как сделать нужные изменения :)

Comment: typescript сам это проверяет при передаче, ничего дополнительно не нужно

Comment: @EzioMercer, зачем делать изменения, если и так все работает? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy Ну судя по коду в вопросе я предположил, что надо, чтобы после компиляции осталась проверка :) Ну а так понятно, что TS сам всё может проверять :)